# OR operator between function calls

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

Is there ANY difference whatsoever between:

```
if (!bool_function()) {
  void_function();
}
```

and

```
bool_function() || void_function();
```

aside from readability?

May I use the 2nd form even though the second function is returning void?
Is it guaranteed in all C-based programming languages (C++, C#, Java) that the `void_function` does not get executed if the `bool_function` returns true?

**EDIT**:
The reason why I'm asking is because on my C compiler is doesn't even give any warning, and it works as expected. I'm using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE.

Comment: This is no valid Java, and i doubt it will be even valid C

Comment: This won't compile in C#.

Comment: `bool_function() || void_function();` Don't know if C supports it, but java doesn't. All the components of a boolean expression must be boolean, so a void is not allowed.

Comment: Well...in Java you can apply the `||` operator for booleans also, which means that `bool_function()||void_function()` won't compile, because `void_funcion()` doesn't return `boolean`.

Comment: This is what `gcc` says: `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be bool_function() || void_function();`

Answer (score 11):

Well, yes, the second doesn't compile.

You can't `or` a bool and a void.

UPDATE: You say your C compiler compiles this and it works fine. I doubt it. That is, I'm sure your compiler compiles it, but what is the result of `bool || void`? Is `void` always true? Always false? Sometimes one and sometimes the other?

In short - don't do it. Use the first form that tells everybody reading your code exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Please give more details about "doesn't compile". See my edit: it works fine on C.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru Are you sure that the `void_function` is actually defined as returning `void`? If the return type is simply omitted, it defaults to `int`. (And of course `void *` is not the same as `void`.)

Comment: @Arkku It is void. The compiler is set to C99, I'm not sure exactly what compiler it is, it comes built-in into IAR.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru Ok, I'm not able to test with that compiler, but it is definitely an exception to the rule. By the way, if you add a cast `(void)` after the `||`, does it still work? That is, `boolf() || (void) voidf();`.

Comment: I forget where in the C standard it's declared, but casting from `void` to other types is *undefined behavior*, thus is not required to be an error.

Comment: @zmbq While I appreciate your intentions to help, I would appreciate more if you kept your answer straight on the subject. I don't see how your "doubting" a reality helps me. Thank you

Comment: I think you should join me in doubt. You don't know what your compiler does when calculating bool || void. What's the 'truth' value of void? The best we know, as @Drew McGowen said, is that it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) says that the right hand expression is not evaluated if the left hand one is true. Same seems to be true of [C#](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). If you look into C and C++ specifications presumably they'd say the same thing.

Comment: The right hand expression is not evaluated if the entire expression doesn't compile. This is not legal Java, C++ or C# code. It might be legal C, although I doubt it's legal C99.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no compiling error, I think they are the same. This phenomenal is so-called **Short-Circuit Evaluation**

> bool_function() || void_function();

If bool_function returns non-zero value, the value or OR logical evaluation will be **TRUE** regardless the return of void_function(), hence it will skip performing the later function.

Not all language describe this characteristic, especially some scripting languages. **Short-Circuit Evaluation** increases the complexity of compiler implementation.